# OpenCL Matrix Multiplication Enqueue/Buffer Reading

Tags: parallel-processing, opencl, matrix-multiplication

I'm attempting a basic matrix multiplication program in OpenCL. I believe my issues are in my enqueue and/or buffer reading, as I am getting completely incorrect output for the result matrix, as well as incorrect first rows for matrices A and B. I'm new to OpenCL and I've been banging my head against this for quite a while now, maybe someone here can give me a hint as to where I'm going wrong?

Host Code:

```
#define __NO_STD_VECTOR // Uses cl::vector instead of standard version
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>

/* Defined matrix width/height constants */
#define numRowsA 3
#define numColsA 3
#define numRowsB 3
#define numColsB 3
#define numRowsC numRowsA
#define numColsC numColsB

using namespace std;

/* Function declarations */
inline void checkErr(cl_int err, string name);
void initMatrix (float* matrix, int numIndices);
void printMatrix (string displayName, float* matrix, int numIndices,  
      int rowSize);

//*************
// Main Program
//*************
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    /* Check for valid matrix sizes */
    if (numColsA != numRowsB) {
        cout << "ERROR: Invalid matrix dimensions." << endl;
    } else {

    srand(2013); // Set random seed

    /* Allocate memory for matrices A, B, and C */
    unsigned int sizeA = numRowsA * numColsA;
    unsigned int sizeB = numRowsB * numColsB;
    unsigned int sizeC = numRowsC * numColsC;
    unsigned int memoryA = sizeof(float) * sizeA;
    unsigned int memoryB = sizeof(float) * sizeB;
    unsigned int memoryC = sizeof(float) * sizeC;

    /*
        Allocate memoryA/memoryB/memoryC size blocks of bytes
        (cast from void*)
    */
    float* blockA = (float*) malloc(memoryA);
    float* blockB = (float*) malloc(memoryB);
    float* blockC = (float*) malloc(memoryC);

    /* Initialize matrices A and B */
    initMatrix(blockA, sizeA);
    initMatrix(blockB, sizeB);

    /* Display matrices A and B */
    printMatrix("Matrix A", blockA, sizeA, numColsA);
    printMatrix("Matrix B", blockB, sizeB, numColsB);

    cl_int err;            // Error code
    string platformVendor; // Platform vendor

    /* Create list of platforms */
    cl::vector < cl::Platform > platformList;
    cl::Platform::get(&platformList);

    /*
        Display potential Platform list generation error. If the
        platform list size does not equal 0, CL_SUCCESS (0) is
        sent to the function. If the platform list size does
        equal 0, -1 is sent to the function.
    */
    checkErr(platformList.size()!=0 ? CL_SUCCESS : -1,
            "Platform");

    /*
        Replace empty value of platformVendor with device vendor
        name
    */
    platformList[0].getInfo((cl_platform_info) CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR,
        &platformVendor);

    /* Properties for Context constructor (Use unknown) */
    cl_context_properties cprops[3] =
        {
        CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
        (cl_context_properties) (platformList[0]) (),
        0
        };

    /* Create context */
    cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, cprops, NULL, NULL,
        &err);

    /* Display potential Context constructor error */
    checkErr(err, "Context");

    /* Create buffer for matrix A */
    cl::Buffer deviceMemA(context,
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeA, blockA, &err);

    /* Create buffer for matrix B */
    cl::Buffer deviceMemB(context,
            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeB, blockB, &err);

    /* Create buffer for matrix C */
    cl::Buffer deviceMemC(context,
            CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeC, blockC, &err);

    /* Create buffer for row (A) and col (C) */
    cl::Buffer rowA(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int),
            (void *) numRowsA, &err);
    cl::Buffer colC(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int),
            (void *) numColsC, &err);

    /* Display potential Buffer constructor error */
    checkErr(err, "Buffers");

    /* Get list of devices */
    cl::vector<cl::Device> devices =
        context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();

    /* Check for at least one device, if not throw error */
    checkErr(devices.size() > 0 ? CL_SUCCESS : -1, "No Devices");

    /* Read input from .cl file */
    ifstream file("matrixMult1_kernels.cl");

    /* Check for potential problem opening .cl input file */
    checkErr(file.is_open() ? CL_SUCCESS:-1, "File Not Open");

    /* Store file contents in a string */
    string prog(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
            (istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    /* Create source object */
    cl::Program::Sources source(1, make_pair(prog.c_str(),
        prog.length()+1));

    /* Create program for given context and source */
    cl::Program program(context, source);

    err = program.build(devices, ""); // Check for build error

    /* Display potential program build error */
    checkErr(err, "Program Build");

    /* Create kernel */
    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "matrixMul", &err);

    /* Display potential Kernel constructor error */
    checkErr(err, "Kernel");

    /*
        Set matrixMul arguments, error checking after each
        argument
    */
    err = kernel.setArg(0, deviceMemA);
    checkErr(err, "Arg0");
    err = kernel.setArg(1, deviceMemB);
    checkErr(err, "Arg1");
    err = kernel.setArg(2, deviceMemC);
    checkErr(err, "Arg2");
    err = kernel.setArg(3, rowA);
    checkErr(err, "Arg3");
    err = kernel.setArg(4, colC);
    checkErr(err, "Arg4");

    /* Create command queue */
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, devices[0], 0, &err);

    /* Display potential CommandQueue constructor error */
    checkErr(err, "Command Queue");

    /* Create event object */
    cl::Event event;

    cl::NDRange global(3, 3);
    cl::NDRange local(1, 1);

    /* Enqueue the kernel */
    err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, 2, global, local,
        NULL, &event);

    /* Display potential enqueueing error */
    checkErr(err, "Enqueue");

    /* Wait until kernel has completed execution before continuing */
    event.wait();

    /* Read kernel result back into host memory */
    err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(deviceMemC, CL_TRUE, 0, memoryC,
        blockC, NULL, &event);

        checkErr(err, "C");

    err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(deviceMemA, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeA,
        blockA, NULL, &event);
    err = queue.enqueueReadBuffer(deviceMemB, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeB,
        blockB, NULL, &event);

    /* Display potential kernel read error */
    checkErr(err, "Read Buffer");

    /* Display matrices */
        cout << endl;
        cout << "After:" << endl;
    printMatrix("Matrix A", blockA, sizeA, numColsA);
    printMatrix("Matrix B", blockB, sizeB, numColsB);
    printMatrix("Matrix C", blockC, sizeC, numColsC);

    /* Free up memory */
    free(blockA);
    free(blockB);
    free(blockC);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// checkErr - Inline error checking function for OpenCL portion of
//            host program.
//
// PRE:  err is of type int in OpenCL; name is a string.
// POST: The program is terminated after display an error message
//       indicating the location of the error and the error code.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
inline void checkErr(cl_int err, string name) {

    /* Check error code against OpenCL success constant */
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {

    /*
        Display an error message stating the error origin and
        error number.
    */
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << name << " (" << err << ")"
              << std::endl;

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); // Terminates process with status code 0
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// initMatrix - Assigns a random float value to each indice of the
//              matrix.
//
// PRE:  matrix is a pointer to a block of bytes in memory; numIndices
//       is the number of indicies in the matrix being instantiated.
// POST: Each index of the matrix has been instantiated with a random
//       float value.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void initMatrix (float* matrix, int numIndices) {

    /*
    Loop through the block of bytes, assigning a random float
    for each index of the matrix
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; i++) {

    /* Assign a random float between 0 and 1 at this byte */
    matrix[i] = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// printMatrix - Outputs a readable version of the matrix.
//
// PRE:  displayName is a string; matrix is a pointer to a block of
//       bytes in memory; numIndices an integer indicating the number
//       of indices in the matrix being displayed (read left-to-right,
//       top-to-bottom); rowSize is an integer indicating the number
//       of elements in one row of the matrix.
// POST: A readable version of the matrix is displayed.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void printMatrix (string displayName, float* matrix, int numIndices,
          int rowSize) {

    /* Output display name of matrix */
    cout << "\n" << displayName << ":" << endl;

    /* Loop through each indice of the matrix */
    for (int i = 0; i < numIndices; i++) {
    cout << matrix[i]; // Display value at this indice

    /* Check for next row of the matrix */
    if (((i + 1) % rowSize) == 0) {
        cout << endl; // Line break
    } else {
        cout << "  |  "; // Indice separator
    }
    }
}
```

Kernel:

```
// matrixMult1_kernels.cl
// Multiply two matrices A * B = C
// Device code.

// OpenCL Kernel
__kernel void
matrixMul(__global float* A, 
          __global float* B, 
      __global float* C, 
          int wA, int wB) {

   // 2D Thread ID
   int tx = get_local_id(0);
   int ty = get_local_id(1);

   // value stores the element 
   // that is computed by the thread
   float value = 0;

   for (int k = 0; k < wA; ++k)
   {
       float elementA = A[ty * wA + k];
       float elementB = B[k * wB + tx];
       value += elementA * elementB;
   }

   // Write the matrix to device memory each 
   // thread writes one element
   C[ty * wA + tx] = value;
}
```

Sample Output:

> Matrix A:
>
> 0.398748 | 0.999793 | 0.206833
>
> 0.354238 | 0.674347 | 0.492022
>
> 0.707017 | 0.353635 | 0.430668
>
> Matrix B:
>
> 0.91598 | 0.0260167 | 0.881732
>
> 0.810974 | 0.193091 | 0.589857
>
> 0.229151 | 0.0657822 | 0.965835
>
> ERROR: C (-30)

I'm working with an NVIDIA GeForce 9800 GT, which only supports OpenCL 1.1. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data for input matrices A and B is not passed to the device. When you create the buffers:

```
cl::Buffer deviceMemA(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, memoryA,blockA, &err)
```

the **blockA** argument is ignored, because the flags do not specify how to use it. You need to add at least **CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR** to initialize the buffer with the contents of **blockA**.

Alternatively, you can call **clEnqueueWriteBuffer** to send the data after the buffers are created.

Comment: Thanks! The buffers are now of the format cl::Buffer deviceMemA(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, memoryA, blockA, &err); (Except for C, which is write only). Now I'm getting an invalid command queue error on my buffer reads based on the last line of the kernel code, which sets the value to the specified position in Matrix C.

Comment: Your buffer reads should pass the size of buffer in bytes, like memoryC, not the size{A,B,C} values. Also, you are reading 3 times buffer C in your code.

Comment: Hmm, I changed the buffer sizes to sizeA, sizeB, and sizeC and I had already picked up on the buffer x 3 part. Now it's an invalid command queue error. I'll admit, I don't know what's going on with those NDRange fellas, are they correct? Thanks again!

Comment: Global size should be the dimensions of the output matrix. Local size should divide global size. Try with 1,1 for local size to debug. enqueueReadBuffer wants the size in bytes, memoryC, not the size in floats sizeC.

Comment: Hmm, same invalid command queue error... Do you have any tutorials that you'd recommend? I feel bad holding you up on my dinky 3x3 matrix code.

Comment: I also updated the code in the question to reflect the changes I've made.